# CSS :after and :before generated content in input is not clickable

Tags: css

I'm working on some code that I didn't create myself. Select inputs have a custom arrow icon designed with CSS generated content applied to the :before and :after Pseudo sectors.

The issue is that these obstruct the input behind them, so when you click on them the input is not clicked. Is it possible to use CSS generated content in this way but have the whole input clickable?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvAtJ

```
<div class="elem">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
.elem {
  float: right;
}
.elem:before {
  content: "";
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 30px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: -6px 0 10px #FFF;
-moz-box-shadow: -6px 0 10px #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: -6px 0 10px #FFF;
}
.elem:after {
content: "";
border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
border-left: 7px solid transparent;
border-right: 7px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 13px;
}
select {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done with CSS only

Comment: sure it can. check my fiddle below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by  setting the `background` of the select to `transparent` and `z-index` it above the pseudo element. You may also want to set
    `-webkit-appearance: none;  -moz-appearance: none; text-indent: 5px; text-overflow: '';` 
to remove the default styling for webkit and mozilla. check my codepen.

http://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/vIbmG

Comment: Only issue is that it relies on -webkit-appearance: none; so wont look good in firefox, etc.

Comment: you can also add 

-moz-appearance: none; 
text-indent: 5px; 
text-overflow: '';

to get it to work in mozilla. (thanks João Cunha on the mozilla bug forums). I have updated my pen below.

http://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/vIbmG